# Request method 'GET' not supported Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Столкнулся с проблемой Request method 'GET' not supported.
Вот контроллер

```
@PostMapping("add")
public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String,Object> model){
    Message message = new Message(text, tag);
    messageRepos.save(message);
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepos.findAll();
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}
@PostMapping("filter")
public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Map<String, Object> model){
    Iterable<Message> messageList;
    if(filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
        messageList = messageRepos.findByTag(filter);
    }else {
        messageList = messageRepos.findAll();
    }
    model.put("messages", messageList);
    return "main";
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="filter">
        <input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Looking for ...">
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="post" action="add">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Messages"/>
        <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="tag">
        <button type="submit">ADD</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что вы же как-то этот `HTML` получаете, так ведь? Получаете, путем создания `GET` запроса(когда `URL` вводите в браузере и нажимаете на `enter`, вы отправляете именно этот тип запроса). А у вас, как вижу, такого обработчика нет.